# How can i generate int array from string?

Tags: java

The user suppose to enter numbers at this pattern:   `"( -2 , 9)"   OR   "(-2,-3) , etc".`
I am building a `x,y` graph and I need the dots.
How can I get this digits into an int array?

Comment: When you attempted this yourself, where did you get stuck?

Comment: Ok , after the user enter his input, the variable call dots1 im write this: dots1 = dots1.replaceAll("[^\\d-]",""). know if he wrotes the numbers -9,9 for example i will get -99 but if i want to take each digit im stuck, i tried to convert it to char array and its problematic because the sign "-". when im trying with positive number its ok

Comment: @Eran I want to see the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing as good as good 'ol string manipulation:

- Replace ")" and "(" with "".
- Call String.split() to get a String array.
- Allocate an int array of the same length.
- Cycle over the String array to call Integer.parseInt() for each element.

That should do it.

Comment: i dont understand. if i replace '(' and ')' i will stay with ','  what is String.split?

Comment: Please search for String class in Java on google, you'll understand what he meant

Comment: how i replace the '(' AND ')'?

Comment: Use replace function of String class, check this out: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
Parameters p = new Parameters();
NumberVariable[] iV = IntegerVariable.newArray(2);
Format.printf("Enter two values: "); 
Format.scanf("(%i, %i)", p.add(iV[0]).add(iV[1]));
```